# Excel YIELD function in R

Tags: r, excel

I am trying to figure out how the YIELD function in Excel runs its calculations so that I can create a similar function in R that uses similar inputs. Here is the Excel documentation about the function:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/yield-function-HP010343047.aspx

It doesn't give a clear explanation of the steps involved in discovering the yield.

So, what are the equations used in the YIELD function when there is more than one coupon payment until redemption? Is there more in-depth documentation on how the Excel YIELD function works? Maybe there is already a function in R that will allow me to find the yield of a bond given a price?

Comment: Yup. You can use `uniroot()` for it once you set up your objective function:  value should be then sum of discounted cashflows when discounted at this very rate you are seeking.

Comment: Thanks. I have seen uniroot() used an simple yield function, but I am having a hard time setting up what my objective function should be.

Comment: Maybe look at some primers like http://www.moneychimp.com/articles/finworks ?  I agree that it's a **bad thing** (TM) to depend on Excel since not only their code, but often their algorithms, are proprietary and not revealed. It would be nice at the least to know what they are iterating over!