# equivalent "yield" excel function in python?

Tags: python, excel-formula

There is an equivalent function to Excel/LibreOffice [yield](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/YIELD-function-f5f5ca43-c4bd-434f-8bd2-ed3c9727a4fe) in python? There is the equivalent question for R [Excel YIELD function in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23297794/excel-yield-function-in-r) but without answers. Someone have an idea where to find the algorithm?

I have a excel spreadsheet. I'd like performing the same computation with python. So I need the same functions that I have in excel. I am implementing [yearfrac](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/YEARFRAC-function-3844141E-C76D-4143-82B6-208454DDC6A8). Maybe someone had the same kind of issue. Anyway libreoffice must have already implemented the some excel functions.

**update**

I have found the libreoffice source [here](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/cgit/?url=libreoffice/core/tree/scaddins/source/analysis/analysishelper.cxx&id=78dde8745e6fbc9ca73378d0ef093f3159d25d16#n1078). In the next few days I will try to implements it in python.

Comment: To my knowledge, no, but there is no reason why you couldn't write one yourself

Comment: @wnnmaw Yes, I can do,  but without knowing the algorithm is how to look for the keys in the dark.

Comment: @Giovanni can you share with your implementation of libreoffice functions?

Answer (score 2):

Based on a quick Google search, it looks like the [qfrm package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/qfrm) might have what you're looking for.