# There doesn't seem to be any bond/security yield function in python libraries

Tags: python

I'm looking for a simple Bond Yield function in Python similar to the YIELD function in Excel. Having spent several hours looking, I can't seem to find one.

The only similar post is this one here, but the library hasn't been worked on since 2015.

[equivalent "yield" excel function in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36226698/equivalent-yield-excel-function-in-python)

It seems like a very basic finance function, I wonder if anyone has a suggestion?

Comment: what that function is doing in excel ?

Comment: Answered here: https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/36028/excel-yield-function-equivalent-in-python-quantlib

Comment: See more for well formed questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Does [this question](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/36028/excel-yield-function-equivalent-in-python-quantlib) help? It uses the QuantLib library.

Comment: Thanks for the note on how to ask a better question. Will try to do better in future. 

I have seen the QuantLib question actually. The problem is that QuantLib is a very complex library, I've explored it for option pricing before, it feels a bit like trying to kill an ant with a grenade launcher! I was trying to figure out a slightly more straight forward method, but I will give it a go as you suggest.